# load time of applet in embeded web page

Tags: internet-explorer, applet, ie-developer-tools

need to take load time metrics of a web page which has applet object.

I tried using developer tool but looks like it is not counting applet waiting or loading time

is their any such tool which will give proper exact time includes applet objects load times.

Comment: It's possible if you control the applet code and the HTML.  Then you can put a method the applet that JS can poll.

Comment: do i need to write some code in javascript to calculate the timings?

Comment: Did you think there'd be a `timeJavaApplet()` funtion?